# How to delete a reference from list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I have some references that I added in front of some figures and I don't want it to be shown in the page of figures:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{images/rmi.png}
\caption{text[5]}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}
```

I want to delete `[5]` from table of figures. How to do that?

Comment: Apparently you have made some mistake in using the caption, but it's unclear. Please post the compilable code that shows this issue!

Comment: My crystal ball is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your can do something like this

```
\caption[short]{Long}
```

In your example -

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{images/rmi.png}
\caption[text]{text [5]}
\label{fig:text}
\end{figure}
```

This will give your caption without reference in tof.

Comment: do you understand what I want to do?I just want to delete [5] from figure contents table not from the caption

Comment: I edited it again by using [5] instead of cite. This will give your reference in your figure caption but not in table of figures. Hopefully that's what your want. Dont you ?